# How to make one line bold in multiline plot in matplotlib or seaborn?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have a multiple line plot where I want to make one of the lines green and thick and the other ones grey.
my plot currently looks like this.[image]

here is a sample (reproducible) code. for example, I want the line for Astrakhan to be a thick green and the other ones to be grey.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = {'year': ['1998','1998','1998','1998','1998','1998','1998','1999','1999','1999','1999','1999','1999','1999'],'region':['Adygea','Altai Krai','Amur Oblast','Arkhangelsk','Astrakhan','Bashkortostan','Belgorod','Adygea','Altai Krai','Amur Oblast','Arkhangelsk','Astrakhan','Bashkortostan','Belgorod'],  'sales':[8.8, 19.2,21.2, 10.6,18,17.5,23, 10, 17.8, 20.5, 12.6, 19.9, 16, 21]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))

palette1 = {c:'#079b51' if c=='Astrakhan' else 'grey' for c in df['region'].unique()}

sns.lineplot(x= 'year', y='sales', data=df,hue='region', palette=palette1)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')
```

However, I dont know how to increase the thickness. I have tried setting size and linewidth similar to palette, and it does not work this way. thank you.

Comment: `palette = {c:'green' if c=='Astrakhan' else 'grey' for c in df['region'].unique()}`

Comment: or, with palette=palette as a parameter, I am getting a single line.

Comment: `sns.lineplot(x= 'year', y='sales', data=df,hue='region', palette=palette)`

Comment: thank u : ) I have figured it out eventually. do you also know how to make it bold?